# [dcc32 Fatal Error]: F2084 Internal Error: NC1921

Tags: delphi, dcc32

I'm trying to compile the following code in Delphi Rio:

```
unit untObjectHelper;

interface

uses
   SysUtils;

type
   TObjectHelper = class(TInterfacedObject)
   public
      class procedure Clone(const objOrigem: TObject; const objDestino: TObject);
   end;

implementation

uses
   System.Rtti;

{ TObjectHelper }

class procedure TObjectHelper.Clone(const objOrigem,
   objDestino: TObject);
begin
   if not Assigned(objOrigem) then
      Exit;

   if not Assigned(objDestino) then
      Exit;

   if objOrigem.ClassType <> objDestino.ClassType then
      Exit;

   var contexto := TRttiContext.Create;
   try
      var tipo := contexto.GetType(objOrigem.ClassType);
      var campos := tipo.GetFields();
   finally
      contexto.Free;
   end;
end;

end.
```

however the following error occurs:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] untObjectHelper.pas (36): F2084 Internal Error:
>   NC1921

on the line:

```
var fields: = type.GetFields ();
```

version: Embarcadero® Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.33219.4899

I did not find reference to this error, could someone help me? thank you very much

Comment: Looks like something you should be reporting to QC. Not surprised with the introduction of in-line variables. Try pre-declaring that variable, or both. Probably a combination of that + RTTI.

Comment: I don't have Rio, but in Seattle, you can't declare a variable named "Type". So, I'd try to rename the variable something else, or use "&Type".

Comment: @LURD, i fixed the code, was the translator

Comment: @JerryDodge you are correct, declaring in the variable section, the code compiled

Comment: @KenBourassa, i fixed the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the type inference, thanks to Rudy Velthuis for the tip

```
unit untObjectHelper;

interface

uses
   SysUtils;

type
   TObjectHelper = class(TInterfacedObject)
   public
      class procedure Clone(const objOrigem: TObject; const objDestino: TObject);
   end;

implementation

uses
   System.Rtti;

{ TObjectHelper }

class procedure TObjectHelper.Clone(const objOrigem,
   objDestino: TObject);
begin
   if not Assigned(objOrigem) then
      Exit;

   if not Assigned(objDestino) then
      Exit;

   if objOrigem.ClassType <> objDestino.ClassType then
      Exit;

   var contexto := TRttiContext.Create;
   try
      var tipo := contexto.GetType(objOrigem.ClassType);
      var campos: TArray<TRttiField> := tipo.GetFields();
   finally
      contexto.Free;
   end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use your original code with the following amendment: `var campos: TArray<TRttiField> := tipo.GetFields();`. The problem is not the inline declaration, the problem is the type inference, which doesn't work properly.